# How to fix this postgresql error `FATAL: password authentication failed for user <user>?

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I'm trying to setup a simple server using IntelliJ Community, Spring Boot and PostgreSQL.

I was following an online tutorial and downloaded the [code from this github](https://github.com/Fernanda-Kipper/live-crud-java-spring/tree/initial-template) as an initial template. It should be a template generated by this website: https://start.spring.io/.

Bellow is the error log. How do I fix it?

```
2023-06-02T11:30:49.064-03:00  WARN 12340 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Unable to obtain connection from database: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "fernandakipper"
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 28P01
Error Code : 0
Message    : FATAL: password authentication failed for user "fernandakipper"

2023-06-02T11:30:49.071-03:00  INFO 12340 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-06-02T11:30:49.095-03:00  INFO 12340 --- [  restartedMain] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-06-02T11:30:49.140-03:00 ERROR 12340 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Unable to obtain connection from database: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "fernandakipper"
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 28P01
Error Code : 0
Message    : FATAL: password authentication failed for user "fernandakipper"

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1770) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:598) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:520) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:313) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1156) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:931) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:608) ~[spring-context-6.0.9.jar:6.0.9]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:733) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:435) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:311) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1305) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1294) ~[spring-boot-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
    at com.example.crud.CrudApplication.main(CrudApplication.java:10) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.1.0.jar:3.1.0]
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: Unable to obtain connection from database: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "fernandakipper"
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : 28P01
Error Code : 0
Message    : FATAL: password authentication failed for user "fernandakipper"
```

Comment: Pretty straightforward the password you supplied for `fernandakipper` is not the correct one.

Comment: The unauthenticated client gets an intentionally vague error message.  Look in the database server's log file for a more complete message.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver Not necessarily.  It could also be that the password was never assigned, or has expired, or that the user doesn't even exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to install postgresql in your local and change the properties as per your db configuration. What they had provided is dummy. You have to put the actuals to make it work as expected